# Sheet shared during script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a script to help a school take attendance during COVID. In fact, the students are reporting their own attendance. The problem is, the sheet that I write the information to is being shared automatically with each student. The school doesn't want that. Is there a way to prevent the share or disconnect the share at the end of the script?

```
function submitAttendance() {

  // source spreadsheets
  var sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0];

  //destination spreadsheet
  var destinationSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1TtTUGAjd99q1WNbPxicWTuJkhyCHteqZ25C_vnKZzQU');
  var destSheet = destinationSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0]; 

  // Get the contents of a cell in srcSheet
  var name = srcSheet.getRange(8, 12);
  var date = srcSheet.getRange(7, 12);
  //var period = srcSheet.getRange(8, 5);
  var names = name.getValues();
  var dates = date.getValues();
  //var periods = period.getValues();
  
  // Get active user
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  
  // use Checkboxes
  for(var row = 9; row <=16; row++){
    var range = srcSheet.getRange(row,13);
    var isTicked = range.isChecked();
    if (isTicked == 1){
      var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
      var period = row - 8;
      destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1).setValue(new Date());
      destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,2).setValue(email);
      destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,3).setValue(names);
      destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,4).setValue(dates);
      destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,5).setValue(period);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this `var name = srcSheet.getRange(8, 12);
  var date = srcSheet.getRange(7, 12);
  //var period = srcSheet.getRange(8, 5);
  var names = name.getValues();
  var dates = date.getValues();` should use `getValue()` instead of `getValues().`

Answer (score 3):

You could try using Google Forms for your students to submit attendance, and that way the response sheet doesn't need to be shared with them. Only the form. And you can also use your script with that response sheet as desired. You may find some interesting solutions [here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/41998257?hl=en) and also in this [Quickstart: Managing Responses for Google Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms).